# How do I insert "Created by" into a concatenate formula?

Tags: calculated-column-formula, calculated-column

To have month view in a SharePoint calendar which displays the value of more than one field.

I would like to combine the Title with the user's name using calculated column type.
But Createdby can't be used in the formula

Title& ....

Can someone tell me how I can show the values of both title and user name in the month view of a SharePoint ?

Many thanks in advance.

Martine.

Answer (score 1):

Created By is a "People Picker" field, and those are not supported by SharePoint Calculated Columns. You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow to copy a selected "people" property into a Single Line of Text column that can be used by a Calculated Column.

This is showing a dialog from the workflow designer. It is using a "Boss" column instead of Created By, but both are People columns. You would want the "Display Name" property.

[image]